# Why all the page in the GridView show the same data as that in the first page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I use a GridView to show data from an excel file, after setting the GridView's Allowpage to true. All the pages show the same content as that in the first page. Thanks to anyone who tell me why!

The HTML code of the GrdiView is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_NewStaff" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
 CellPadding="4" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333" AllowPaging="True" 
 AllowSorting="True" onpageindexchanging="GridView_NewStaff_PageIndexChanging" 
 PageSize="20">
 <pagersettings firstpagetext="First" lastpagetext="Last">
     Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" NextPageText="Next" PageButtonCount="4" 
     PreviousPageText="Previous" />
     <columns>......
```

The C# code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bindGridView();
    }
}

protected void Button_ReadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindGridView();
}


public void bindGridView()
{
    if (FileUpload_StaffInfo.HasFile)
    {
        string InfoFile_Name = Server.MapPath(InfoFileDirectory) + FileUpload_StaffInfo.FileName;
        FileUpload_StaffInfo.SaveAs(InfoFile_Name);

        dataTable_Excel = new DataTable();

        if (InfoFile_Name.EndsWith(".xlsx"))//Read Excel2007-2010 format file
        {
            StaffExcelXML StaffNewXML = new StaffExcelXML();
        StaffNewXML.ExcelInput(InfoFile_Name, ref dataTable_Excel)
        }
        else if (InfoFile_Name.EndsWith(".xls"))//Read Excel1997-2003 format file
        {
            StaffXLS StaffNewXLS = new StaffXLS();
        StaffNewXLS.ExcelInput(InfoFile_Name, ref dataTable_Excel);
        }

        GridView_NewStaff.DataSource = dataTable_Excel;
        GridView_NewStaff.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView_NewStaff_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView_NewStaff.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    bindGridView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
GridView_NewStaff.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
bindGridView();
```

to

```
GridView_NewStaff.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
GridView_NewStaff.DataBind();
```

After assigning a new Page index to the GridView, just rebind the GridView control.